# Parsing JSON response in kubernetes Pod proto message failing with compatibilty error

Tags: c++, json, kubernetes, protocol-buffers

I am using google protobuf's JsonStringToMessage function from google/protobuf/json_util.h
I have one json string (pod response). I want to convert/parse that json string response into kubernetes Pod message.

But, parsing is failing with error "invalid value "2023-08-11T07:37:33Z" for type type.googleapis.com/v1_25.k8s.io.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.Time"

Sample pod response -

```html
object {
  raw: "{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Pod\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"cni.projectcalico.org/containerID\":\"2db21ede98ad7d1d02f56b2ddacd2e6ce6d1bccce572f99aef0a1dc7010ec5ef\",\"cni.projectcalico.org/podIP\":\"10.244.74.210/32\",\"cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs\":\"10.244.74.210/32\",\"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration\":\"{\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"v1\\\",\\\"kind\\\":\\\"Pod\\\",\\\"metadata\\\":{\\\"annotations\\\":{},\\\"name\\\":\\\"sp-pod\\\",\\\"namespace\\\":\\\"sp2\\\"},\\\"spec\\\":{\\\"containers\\\":[{\\\"image\\\":\\\"nginx\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"my-container\\\",\\\"volumeMounts\\\":[{\\\"mountPath\\\":\\\"/data\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"data-volume\\\"}]}],\\\"volumes\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"data-volume\\\",\\\"persistentVolumeClaim\\\":{\\\"claimName\\\":\\\"data-vault-banzaicloud-consul-consul-server-1\\\"}}]}}\\n\"},\"creationTimestamp\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:00Z\",\"managedFields\":[{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"fieldsType\":\"FieldsV1\",\"fieldsV1\":{\"f:metadata\":{\"f:annotations\":{\".\":{},\"f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration\":{}}},\"f:spec\":{\"f:containers\":{\"k:{\\\"name\\\":\\\"my-container\\\"}\":{\".\":{},\"f:image\":{},\"f:imagePullPolicy\":{},\"f:name\":{},\"f:resources\":{},\"f:terminationMessagePath\":{},\"f:terminationMessagePolicy\":{},\"f:volumeMounts\":{\".\":{},\"k:{\\\"mountPath\\\":\\\"/data\\\"}\":{\".\":{},\"f:mountPath\":{},\"f:name\":{}}}}},\"f:dnsPolicy\":{},\"f:enableServiceLinks\":{},\"f:restartPolicy\":{},\"f:schedulerName\":{},\"f:securityContext\":{},\"f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds\":{},\"f:volumes\":{\".\":{},\"k:{\\\"name\\\":\\\"data-volume\\\"}\":{\".\":{},\"f:name\":{},\"f:persistentVolumeClaim\":{\".\":{},\"f:claimName\":{}}}}}},\"manager\":\"kubectl-client-side-apply\",\"operation\":\"Update\",\"time\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:00Z\"},{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"fieldsType\":\"FieldsV1\",\"fieldsV1\":{\"f:metadata\":{\"f:annotations\":{\"f:cni.projectcalico.org/containerID\":{},\"f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIP\":{},\"f:cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs\":{}}}},\"manager\":\"calico\",\"operation\":\"Update\",\"subresource\":\"status\",\"time\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:09Z\"},{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"fieldsType\":\"FieldsV1\",\"fieldsV1\":{\"f:status\":{\"f:conditions\":{\"k:{\\\"type\\\":\\\"ContainersReady\\\"}\":{\".\":{},\"f:lastProbeTime\":{},\"f:lastTransitionTime\":{},\"f:status\":{},\"f:type\":{}},\"k:{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Initialized\\\"}\":{\".\":{},\"f:lastProbeTime\":{},\"f:lastTransitionTime\":{},\"f:status\":{},\"f:type\":{}},\"k:{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Ready\\\"}\":{\".\":{},\"f:lastProbeTime\":{},\"f:lastTransitionTime\":{},\"f:status\":{},\"f:type\":{}}},\"f:containerStatuses\":{},\"f:hostIP\":{},\"f:phase\":{},\"f:podIP\":{},\"f:podIPs\":{\".\":{},\"k:{\\\"ip\\\":\\\"10.244.74.210\\\"}\":{\".\":{},\"f:ip\":{}}},\"f:startTime\":{}}},\"manager\":\"kubelet\",\"operation\":\"Update\",\"subresource\":\"status\",\"time\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:12Z\"}],\"name\":\"sp-pod\",\"namespace\":\"sp2\",\"resourceVersion\":\"16056279\",\"uid\":\"c426949c-b4a9-4148-b048-82cad3ec625f\"},\"spec\":{\"containers\":[{\"image\":\"nginx\",\"imagePullPolicy\":\"Always\",\"name\":\"my-container\",\"resources\":{},\"terminationMessagePath\":\"/dev/termination-log\",\"terminationMessagePolicy\":\"File\",\"volumeMounts\":[{\"mountPath\":\"/data\",\"name\":\"data-volume\"},{\"mountPath\":\"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount\",\"name\":\"kube-api-access-q2shq\",\"readOnly\":true}]}],\"dnsPolicy\":\"ClusterFirst\",\"enableServiceLinks\":true,\"nodeName\":\"swift-dev-2\",\"preemptionPolicy\":\"PreemptLowerPriority\",\"priority\":0,\"restartPolicy\":\"Always\",\"schedulerName\":\"default-scheduler\",\"securityContext\":{},\"serviceAccount\":\"default\",\"serviceAccountName\":\"default\",\"terminationGracePeriodSeconds\":30,\"tolerations\":[{\"effect\":\"NoExecute\",\"key\":\"node.kubernetes.io/not-ready\",\"operator\":\"Exists\",\"tolerationSeconds\":300},{\"effect\":\"NoExecute\",\"key\":\"node.kubernetes.io/unreachable\",\"operator\":\"Exists\",\"tolerationSeconds\":300}],\"volumes\":[{\"name\":\"data-volume\",\"persistentVolumeClaim\":{\"claimName\":\"data-vault-banzaicloud-consul-consul-server-1\"}},{\"name\":\"kube-api-access-q2shq\",\"projected\":{\"defaultMode\":420,\"sources\":[{\"serviceAccountToken\":{\"expirationSeconds\":3607,\"path\":\"token\"}},{\"configMap\":{\"items\":[{\"key\":\"ca.crt\",\"path\":\"ca.crt\"}],\"name\":\"kube-root-ca.crt\"}},{\"downwardAPI\":{\"items\":[{\"fieldRef\":{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"fieldPath\":\"metadata.namespace\"},\"path\":\"namespace\"}]}}]}}]},\"status\":{\"conditions\":[{\"lastProbeTime\":null,\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:00Z\",\"status\":\"True\",\"type\":\"Initialized\"},{\"lastProbeTime\":null,\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:12Z\",\"status\":\"True\",\"type\":\"Ready\"},{\"lastProbeTime\":null,\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:12Z\",\"status\":\"True\",\"type\":\"ContainersReady\"},{\"lastProbeTime\":null,\"lastTransitionTime\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:00Z\",\"status\":\"True\",\"type\":\"PodScheduled\"}],\"containerStatuses\":[{\"containerID\":\"cri-o://9a1bb1abaa0503bcc945182591412a484b47beda993b7906b93fbb99b7e75442\",\"image\":\"docker.io/library/nginx:latest\",\"imageID\":\"docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:67f9a4f10d147a6e04629340e6493c9703300ca23a2f7f3aa56fe615d75d31ca\",\"lastState\":{},\"name\":\"my-container\",\"ready\":true,\"restartCount\":0,\"started\":true,\"state\":{\"running\":{\"startedAt\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:11Z\"}}}],\"hostIP\":\"172.29.40.101\",\"phase\":\"Running\",\"podIP\":\"10.244.74.210\",\"podIPs\":[{\"ip\":\"10.244.74.210\"}],\"qosClass\":\"BestEffort\",\"startTime\":\"2023-08-09T08:06:00Z\"}}"
}
```

Sample code -

```
 string rawData = watch.object().raw(); // Attached image
 cout << rawData << endl;
 v1_25::k8s::io::api::core::v1::Pod pod;
 std::string jsonError;
 JsonParseOptions options;
 options.ignore_unknown_fields = true;
 google::protobuf::util::Status status = JsonStringToMessage(rawData, &pod, options);
 if( status.ok() )
 {
     cout << "success" << endl;
 }
 else cerr << "Failed" << status.error_message() << endl;
```

Comment: I assume you generated your own C++ library for the Kubernetes API as I'm unaware of a published client library. Kubernetes uses the ([deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/96564)) `gogo/protobuf` rather than Google's protobuf and (possibly?) for this reason, the Kubernetes API doesn't use Google's Well-known Types (e.g. Timestamp) but (re)defines its own [`Time`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/6e0cb243d57592c917fe449dde20b0e246bc66be/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/generated.proto#L1078) and `Timestamp`).

Comment: Google's Protobuf libraries handle the conversion between RFC3339 strings to [`Timestamp`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#timestamp) as part of their JSON serialization. I suspect this is missing in your implementation. There's an explanation of this [JSON mapping](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/blob/68463f0e96c93bc19ef36ccd3adfe690bfdb568c/types/known/timestamppb/timestamp.pb.go#L146) in the Golang `timestampb` library that may help you.

Comment: Please don't include images (of text) on Stack overflow particularly when, as in this case, it's trivial to copy the relevant subset of the content as text directly. Image content isn't immediately accessible to people answering questions and may not outlive the question.

Comment: Noted @DazWilkin. Thanks for your suggestion, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is worth a try:
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/json/json.go

there might be tools to call this from c++